# What flags to I need to use for test methods?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and I am struggling decrypting existing code. In particular, a method is tagged with:

```
#[cfg(any(test, feature = "test-helpers"))]
```

So when I try to run `cargo test`, it's not available and I get the message:

> ^^^^ method not found in ...

How do I specify that I want to test with these methods to cargo?

Comment: It should be available with `cargo test`, since it set the `test` flag. Is this in the same crate you're testing?

Comment: It's not the same crate, but it's a crate that's using the crate with that prefix on the method.

Comment: So you probably shouldn't use this method, but if you want, you can turn the `test-helpers` feature.